# adding specific values to excel column when certain conditions are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns,

1. Afghanistan
2. Benin
3. Country

The first 2 columns contains decimal values in them and also some blank spaces in between(represented by '-'). What I want to achieve is that I want to check `if Afghanistan column has any value in it`, if yes, then the corresponding cell of country column in that row should have  `Afghanistan` in it and if in that same row, `Benin column has value`, then the Country column should have `Benin` in it and `if both have values in them` then Country cell should have `Afghanistan, Benin` in it. Also, if there is a value already present in the Country column, then it should not be changed. How can it be achieved?

Please help me as I'm a total newbie in excel.

Thanks

Please see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyZUq.png)

Comment: Benin is a clumn name or a value is Column name? "the corresponding cell of country column in that row should have Afghanistan in it" refers to which column?

Comment: Afghanistan ,Benin and Country are 3 column names and afghanistan and benin have values in them. I need to check if afghanistan and benin have value then enter their name into the country column.

Comment: I have added a picture in my question. I hope this clarifies my question a little bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA, assuming a new Country (I name it Country2) column as a solution is acceptable.

Also assume the the 3 original column is A:C & Country2 column is D. Put this is D2 and drag downwards :

`=IF(C2="",IF(AND(B2="-",A2="-"),"",IF(B2="-","Afghanistan",IF(A2="-","Benin","Afghanistan,Benin"))),C2)`

Idea : convert all you logic to nested if. The Column D is your desired column.

---

how it work:

`=IF(C2="", ... ,C2)` If C2 is not empty, take C2 value. If It is empty, do (...)

`IF(AND(B2="-",A2="-"),"", ... )` If both A2 & B2 is empty put a blank : ""  , else do (...)

`IF(B2="-","Afghanistan", ... )` If only B2 is equal to "-", put "Afghanistan", else do ...

`IF(A2="-","Benin","Afghanistan,Benin")` If only A2 is equal to "-", put "Benin", else put "Afghanistan,Benin" .

Comment: If you need to replace the original column content, you'll need to do the save logic above, but in vba.

Comment: can you please explain what are we using c2 for? broadly speaking, i want to know how this works? Thanks

Comment: c2 is your original Country column. | with exel formula you cannot do this part : "if there is a value already present in the Country column, then it should not be changed." | So I propose to create a new Country column @ `D:D`

Comment: So we are just not touching C column? And using nested ifs only for the A and B columns and producing results in D?

Comment: yup. not touching C column. touching C column needs vba (overwriting cells value).

Comment: added the "how this works" part to the answer. /(^_^)

Answer (score 1):

What you might need is the `=ISBLANK()` worksheet function, which can check if a cell is empty or not. This is to be combined with an `=IF()` formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);"Value if true";"Value if false")
```

When you put this, let's say in cell B2, you'll get the expected result.

When you want to check if anything is present inside a column, you might do this:

```
=LEN(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,B2:B6))
```

This concatenates column B (from B2 to B6), using an empty string delimiter, and takes the length of the result. In case there's nothing in that entire column, the length will be zero.

Comment: Is there a way I could do this conditional testing for both my columns at once?

Comment: You can join different strings using `&` concatenation, like `TextJoin(...)&TextJoin(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out but I think `nested if` is the way to go here.

Comment: @MasterMayank: I've written my answer before you uploaded the screenshot. If my answer is helpful anyway, please upvote it, otherwise I'll remove it.